# Extract Instagram Follower/Following Data

Tags: instagram

I wanted to extract Instagram Follower/Following Data(other user, not my own) and also the names/userid of the Follower/Following. I have searched through the forum but so far what I found is that need authentication before could access any basic data from the Instagram user.

May I know is it possible not to go through the authentication but still able to pull the relationship data (following/follower) data?

What I am trying to achieve here is to track for example do a data analysis of how many followers does a particular public profile of a instagram user has (i.e. maybe some newly opened toy shop that has started a instagram profile). Authenticating each and every single shops that have started a public instagram profile is not feasible. Hence, would there be a way to extract that data using going through the authentication process as described by the API?

Thanks.

Comment: I donot think you can achieve this without authenticating . If you want to access the Instagram API you have to go through Authentication process .

Comment: without authenticating you could only get the amount of followers and following, but not the detail (names/user's ID) ... there are users who have millions of followers and you may need to go through lots (and lots) of pagination process to get that data.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is that you need need authentication with some IG account first. After that, the information is all available as long as the account you are looking at is 'public'

Answer (score 0):

API doesn't provide the list of follower anymore even if you are authentificate
You need to do some other technique like the web scraping one (parse the code of the HTML )

Answer (score 0):

This is seriously not my area and the question I was answering to has been closed.
I have spent so long trying to figure this out and although it is a very different solution it's probably going to work for longer.

Open your browser in Mobile mode (no idea how to do).
*I have used a python script which did this for me but I will update it with help from the comments*

Open a New Tab, acess the profile you want to explore and press followers/following respectively.

Looking at the list of followers/folowing

Inspect any element and go to 'Console' at the top

On the console, paste this and hit Enter.

```
const arrHtml = document.getElementsByClassName('_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p  _abb- _abcm');

while (!!arrHtml.length) {
  arrHtml[0].parentNode.removeChild(arrHtml[0])
}
```

And this

```
const arrHtml = document.getElementsByClassName('_ab8w  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p  _abbj _abcm');

while (!!arrHtml.length) {
  arrHtml[0].parentNode.removeChild(arrHtml[0])
}
```

And this

```
const arrHtml = document.getElementsByClassName('_ab8y  _ab94 _ab99 _ab9f _ab9m _ab9p  _aba_ _abcm');

while (!!arrHtml.length) {
  arrHtml[0].parentNode.removeChild(arrHtml[0])
}
```

And this

```
const arrHtml = document.getElementsByClassName('_ab8w  _ab94 _ab97 _ab9h _ab9k _ab9p  _abb0 _abcm');

while (!!arrHtml.length) {
  arrHtml[0].parentNode.removeChild(arrHtml[0])
}
```

Now that everything has been stripped away, except for the usernames.
Click anywhere and use `Ctrl + A`

`Copy (Ctrl + C)`

And paste `(Ctrl + V)` wherever you like. **enjoy'**